# How to get output of dynamic SQL exported in excel using MS SQL Server Management Studio 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I have a query that gives all the details about each table in the schema. But as it is dynamic SQL I am not able to export it's result from SQL Server management Studio 2012. The SQL is:

```
Declare @sql Nvarchar(MAX)
Set @sql = N''

Select @sql = @sql + N'
EXEC sp_help ''['+TABLE_SCHEMA+N'].['+TABLE_NAME+N']'';'
 From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES

Print N'Executing:
'+@sql+'
'
EXEC(@sql)
```

When I try export feature from SQL server Management Studio 2012 I get error as:

[image]

Is there a way I can get output of this query exported in a xls sheet. I can change the query as well as far as it gives details (sp_help tablename) of all the tables present in the schema.

Comment: Have you tried copy and paste from the Result grid?

Comment: The result grid comes in form of 7-8 individual tables for each database table. So I can't copy entire result grid and have to copy each resulting tables one by one. As I have database tables in hundreds, which makes it tedious manual task to copy and paste each table.

Comment: How about inserting the results into a temp table and then exporting this temp table into an Excel file? Anyway, as it is currently setup I understand SSMS. I would also wonder how you want to export all these "tables in the result grid" into Excel file(s). Do you want one Excel file with many tabs? Do you want one Excel file for each resulting table? Or do you want all the table results into one Excel file in one tab and all results below each other (with a few empty rows in between)?

Comment: If I have a choice I would prefer the last option: all the table results into one Excel file in one tab and all results below each other (with a few empty rows in between). But at this moment just getting the result exported in the xls in any form would suffice.

Comment: I'm just curious, what are you using this data for?